# Unused classes in my HTML

Tags: html, performance, browser

Do unused class names on html elements impede rendering performance (with no corresponding style in the style).

eg: I have a number of game types that have a fixed number set, some game types require the number set be styled differently. The game type key is added to the parent of all game types to allow the number set to be styled differently for each game type if required, although most use the default styling as such have unused classes.

Answer (score 1):

Not on active performance. It will only give your stylesheets itself more data-weight to download, but might also seem trivial if you count in browser-caching.

Classes are lazy-loaded and aren't chunked in as a whole into your rendering-set of your browser. They are only searched for when they are needed. If they are never used, it will not impact the performance of your website.

There's one final note tho; if you use different class chains (`.abc .def:nth-child(1) .ghi`) with complex selectors, it might take some browsers a bit time (fractions of miliseconds) to try to still figure out what's happening tho. You really need to benchmark these situations yourself and may differ strongly per browser.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will have to read those, yes, and this will certainly take a little time, but it should not be anywhere near enough time to affect performance in any way you would notice (unless we're talking hundreds or thousands of unused classes maybe). I would consider this a micro-optimization and move on.